# How close to reality is my handwaving argument about Fabry Perot interferometers?

Tags: optics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, mathematics, interferometry

Under [this answer to *https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/55437/7982*](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/55440/7982) I wrote a comment where propose the uncertainty inequality roughly written<sup>1</sup> as $\Delta E \Delta t \ge h$ or for photons $\Delta \nu \Delta t \ge 1$ can be applied to Fabry Perot interferometers where $\Delta t$ is the round-trip time multiplied by the mean number of traversals of a photon before leaking out. I guess that would be when the probability that the photon is still inside drops to 1/e.

Factors of order $2\pi$ aside, is it basically right?

I just ran across this related item in HSM SE: [Uncertainty principle / Fourier results](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/15968/3869)

---

<sup>1</sup>the proper quantum mechanical uncertainty principle for energy and time is written $\sigma_E \sigma_t \ge \frac{h}{2\pi}$

Comment: Basically right.

Comment: @JohnDoty I'd ask this in Optics and Photonics SE instead, but we don't have it... yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Finesse of the LIGO Fabry Perot resonators is (or was when I last updated my lecture notes) about $Q=450$. I call it $Q$ because this is effectively the Q-factor of the resonator.

The relationship between this and the power amplification gain - which is often hand-wavingly used to describe how many time the light travels up and down the arms - is $2Q/\pi = n = 286$ for LIGO.

The Q-factor is the ratio of the frequency of the resonance to the FWHM of the resonance. The relevant frequency is the free spectral range of the interferometer arms, which is $c/2L$. Thus
$$\Delta \nu = \frac{c}{2LQ} = \frac{c}{\pi nL}\ .$$

The "round trip time" for the photons would be $\Delta t = 2nL/c$, and so
$$\Delta \nu \Delta t = \frac{2}{\pi}$$